# A common ancestor for of object delegates in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delegates, ancestor

Is there some common ancestor for Delphi delegates which are declared with `of object` clause?

I need to find a common ancestor for TNotifyEvent and my custom delegate:

```
TMyEvent = procedure(Sender: TObject; msg: stringh); of object;
```

to make an universal method for firing these events.

Should I use Pointer? or TObject?

Comment: Can you give as an example of what you're trying to do. Right now it looks as if you're trying to shoot yourself in the foot by calling methods without supplying all the needed parameters.

Comment: I think you are under the mistaken assumption that `procedure(sender: TObject) of object` and `procedure(Sender: TObject; xyz: TSomehting) of object` are somehow compatible.  They are not! Unless you have the correct signature when calling you will pass the wrong parameters ending in failure.

Comment: I'd love to suggest a solution using generics. But I don't have enough info to formulate a complete answer. Are you trying to make a `TList<TEvent>` which you can then call; is that what you're trying to do? If so I've got an easy answer for that problem.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and speculate that you are trying to design a class with an event property of a type that will accept *either* a `TNotifyEvent` or a `TMyEvent` supplied by the consumer.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Paul, I really dislike these kind of guessing games, sure you can see that we can't help you unless you make your actual problem clear.

Comment: @Johan: I updated the question to include all the neccessary details.

Comment: OK, much improved, which Delphi version?

Comment: If you want to ask a different question do so. I've reverted to the first question that was asked.

Comment: Sorry @Paul, DH's got a point; it's bad form to alter the question to the point that the answer(s) given no longer make sense. Best to copy paste the updated Q in a new Q.

Answer (score 6):

You need to get down and dirty with the implementation details for [method pointers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedural_Types#Method_Pointers). These are stored as a so-called *double pointer* value. One pointer for the subject of the method call (the instance) and one pointer for the method itself (the code).

You can use the type `TMethod` from the `System` unit to represent method pointers. Its declaration looks like so (with the comparison operators removed for simplicity):

```
type
  TMethod = record
    Code, Data: Pointer;
  end;
```

You need to use a typecast to make assignments between these types:

```
uses
  System.Classes;

var
  Event: TNotifyEvent;
  Method: TMethod;

begin
  Method := TMethod(Event);
  TMethod(Event) := Method;
end.
```

Obviously none of this is type-safe so you need to ensure correctness. The compiler cannot help you. There is nothing like the checked type conversion operator, `as`, to work with method pointers. That is, it is up to you that when you cast from `TMethod` to a specific method pointer type, you have to make sure that the `TMethod` instance really is an instance of the method pointer type to which you cast. Think of this whole process as being analogous to casting from a typed pointer to an untyped pointer, and then back again.

Now, if you are going to store arbitrary method pointers into `TMethod` instances, that's fine. But what happens when you subsequently need to fire these methods. You need to know which type of method pointer is really behind each `TMethod` instance. So that you know how to cast it, what arguments it needs, and so how to call it. That's going to mean you have to store extra information about the true type of the method, alongside the raw method itself.

So, I think that I have perhaps answered the question that you asked, but I'm not sure it's going to be of much use to you. To understand that I think we'd really need to know more about what you are trying to achieve, and what information you have, when.

For instance, if you know the arguments that are to be passed to the method at the time you need to store it away, you could use variable capture and wrap it in an anonymous method. That would allow you to retain type-safety and avoid any of the rather dubious casts that I demonstrate above. Perhaps you need [partial application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application), as a means of adapting your non-homogeneous method pointers to have the same interface. In which case again anonymous methods can help.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Esp in light of type safety, I think you have the answer around back to front. You should start with the type-safe option first and only if that fails suggest mucking with TMethod-type hacks.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm still not sure what the underlying problem is so I concentrated on the actual question asked. And I'm loathe to spend much more time on it having already done a fair amount!

Comment: The answer provides more information than is needed. In short: Put to the list through typecast to TMethod, call from the list through PMyEvent(listItem)^ where PMyEvent = ^TMyEvent.

Comment: Nope. That's not right. You need to store two pointers. The answer contains all the information.